# Tomcat 6 path issue on Linux Debian

Tags: linux, debian, tomcat, java

I'm facing an anoying issue on Linux/Debian Tomcat configuration:

I've set up path variables, but when I try to start or shutdown Tomcat nothing happens. Log is empty and the following appears:

```
root@debian:/var/tomcat/bin# ./version.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /var/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /var/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /var/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jdk/bin
Using CLASSPATH:       /var/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar
./catalina.sh: 476: ./catalina.sh: /usr/lib/jdk/bin/bin/java: not found
```

As seen, the last line shows a possible missconfigured environment variable. But I've reviewed installation steps and I couldn't find it. Any idea on what should solve the problem?

Tomcat is version 6 (in directory /var/tomcat). JDK is 1.7.0 update 25 (latest) (in directory /usr/lib/jdk/).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in exporting JAVA_HOME:

Rather /usr/lib/jdk/bin it should be only /usr/lib/jdk.

Everything is working fine now. Hope it would be usefull to sb.